# 'Backbone.history' [undefined] is not an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, rspec, rspec-rails

Hey guys I have a strange problem, when I run rspec tests, **sometimes** displaying a message

> 'http://127.0.0.1:59796/assets/application.js|15727|TypeError: Result
>   of expression 'Backbone.history' [undefined] is not an object

and the test fails.
I start Backbone.history like this:

```
$ ->
  $('body#pages-dashboard').each ->
    new Scanradar.Routers.TasksRouter({tasks: []})
    Backbone.history.start()
```

I don't understand, why it's not working?? Please help me

Answer (score 2):

`Backbone.history` is created the first time you instantiate a router that has routes defined on it.

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-113

If you're seeing this error, it means the router you have tried to create either failed for some reason (an error when instantiating it) or it did not define any routes.

Simply creating a router is not enough. The router must have a route defined on it, or added to it, before the `Backbone.history` object will work.